# I am not able to automate clicking on the Google apps menu items after login to gmail

Tags: java, python, html, selenium, gmail

I am able to open the google apps menu using selenium but I am not able to click on the menu items:
[google apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shSaG.png)

```
//Clicks on google apps link
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("path")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("path")).click();

//Click on menu Item
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.Link("Gmail")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("Gmail")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try :

```
gmail_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath-of-google-button')
gmail_button.click()
```

I think it could work. Finding element by xpath is the most precise tool to scrape the web i think. :)